# Comparison on filter function not working javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, filter, arguments

I have a javascript function which can take two or more arguments.The first argument is always an array of numbers. I need to delete from the array those numbers equal to the other arguments, but my comparison always returns false

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
        var neo=[];
        for(x=1;x<arguments.length;x++){
            neo =arr.filter(function(a){
                return a!=arguments[x] ;
            });
      }
      return neo;
    }


document.write( destroyer( [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3) );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an implementation that uses a filter in combination with the [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method:

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

  return arr.filter(function(i) {
      return args.indexOf(i) < 0;
  });
}


console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3)); // prints [1,1]
```

As to why your original solution doesn't work, there's two factors at play:

1. The `arguments` object you're accessing is the `arguments` object passed down to the filter callback function, not the one passed to your `destroyer` function.
2. On every iteration you're re-initializing your `neo[]` array to an array that has only the last compared value filtered out.

For corrections to your approach, see [Sebi's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32217084/3558960).

Answer (score 2):

The `arguments` your anonymous function sees is not the same `arguments` from your `destroyer` function. Since `arr.filter` calls your callback function, it gets new arguments.

The following fixes the code as it is, see Robby's answer for an alternative approach.

```
function destroyer(arr) {
    var args = arguments;
    return arr.filter(function(a) {
        for(var x = 1; x < args.length; x++) {
            if(args[x] == a) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    });
}
```

It assigns your outer function's arguments to the `args` variable, making them accessible from the anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors in the code, the correct one will be this:

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
    var arg = arguments;
    for(x=1;x<arguments.length;x++){
        arr =arr.filter(function(a){
            return a!=arg[x] ;  //arguments change here
        });
    }
    return arr;
}
```

(1) `arguments` has been changed in the second function. You need to save the previous `arguments` in the closure.

(2) the variable `neo` will remain the same in the second loop, because the `arr` remain the same. Because the `arr` is used as a queue, if you don't want your arr to be changed, you can pass by a clone like `arr.concat()`

And I want to remain that it's the good way to find bug in browser's debug mode. When you use breakpoint to follow the procedure, you will find that things went wrong in the place of second `arguments`

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work in part because you are trying to run a compare with destroyer's arguments[x] in callback function(a) {}, which has its own arguments[x].

Javascript is comparing the array elements to the arguments of function(a){}.

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
        var neo=[];
        for(x=1;x<arguments.length;x++){
            neo =arr.filter(function(a){
                return a!=arguments[x] ;
            });
      }
      return neo;
    }


document.write( destroyer( [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3) );
```